# Почему celery не отправляет письмо в указанное время?

Tags: django, celery

Сделал отправку почты за час до наступления события(модель в django), в shell проверил работает проверка даты, но celery не отправляет ни почту, ни принт в консоль. Есть предчуствие , что что-то не дописал, так как не работал с запланированными действиями еще. но идей нет. Я нигде не подключал shedule.py возомжно в этом причина

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def event_send_mail():
    events = Event.objects.filter(event_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=60))
    for event in events:
        print("Событие")
        send_mail("Напоминание о событии", str(event.title) + "начинаеся через час",
                                     "marsel.abdullin.00@mail.ru", [event.user.email, ])
```

shedule.py:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_mail': {
        'task': 'send_mail',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1),
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно указано имя задачи. Должно быть `tasks.event_send_mail`:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_mail': {
        'task': 'tasks.event_send_mail',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1),
    },
}
```

Ну и `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` должно быть в django `settings`.

Comment: да насчет таска точно подметили, спасибо, но проблема осталась селери в него даже не заходит. В settings задал CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler". Тяжело разобраться как искать проблему